# Error when receive json only Android 4.0

Tags: android, json, web-services

I connect from my Android device to Webservice, then send parameter and get json.
It ok when i test with android API < 4.0 ex 2.3.3 
When i test with another device, it's api is 4.0.3, 4.0.4
then I can not receive json.

This is my code

```
json = getJson("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?result_type=recent&rpp=3&q=iphone");


private String getJson(String uri) {

    String json = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        Log.d(TAG,"1");
        // conn.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000); //6s
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            // get successfull
            // read Json
            Log.d(TAG,"2");
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            int len = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                String s = new String(buf, 0, len);
                stringBuffer.append(s);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"3");

            json = stringBuffer.toString();
            Log.d(TAG,json);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error get json :" + e.toString());
        json = null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Error.

```
11-20 19:42:22.555: E/TEST(29097): error get json :android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Answer (score 4):

it works on your **2.3.3** because the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) has been in android since **api 11**
You need to move the part that uses the `HTTP` connection to another thread, or better use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the webservice from Asynctask<>. The problem will solved.